# how to call the javascript function on table row click

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript function..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RowClick = function() {
        $("#mytable").click(
        $("#showgrid").load('/Products/List/Items/'));
    };
</script>
```

Can I call this function on onclick event on tr?
I am calling something like this?

```
<tr class="something" onclick="javascript:RowClick()');">
can i call like this? if I call its not loading the URL?
```

can anybody help me out?

thanks

Comment: You might also want to take a look here at how to add visual cues to indicate that a row or cell is clickable http://radio.javaranch.com/pascarello/2004/12/30/1104419159000.html

Comment: the "javascript:" protocol in your onclick handler is redundant.. just call `onclick="RowClick();"`

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to call `RowClick()` inline. Just put that code into a click event handler and attach it to each row:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytable tr.something").click(function() {
        $("#showgrid").load('/Products/List/Items/'));
    });
});

<tr class="something">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question you can do the following

```
$("tr").click(function () {
  //call funcion
});
```